# Where can we place config.xml in IOS phone gap?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Hi I am new to IOS and Xcode. Can we use config.xml in IOS xcode? If we are using where can we place the config.xml. While creating my project I did not get config.xml. Is it will be a problem?

Comment: Did you already run the cordova add platform and then cordova build? Please provide more info , you question is still very vague.

Comment: Hi thanks for replay. I don't know how can we create config.xml in IOS phonegap ? Can you guide how to create config.xml and the location of config.xml.

Comment: You didn't answer my questions, hard to help if you do not explain what you did and exactly achieve. Your comment is again the same question you asked.

Comment: Yes I already run my application it is running. But for adding plugins  i need to configure those plugins in config.xml but i did not found my config.xml through out my project.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest versions of cordova tipically update the required files (config.xml) for you when you use the CLI with command
Cordova plugin add

The documentation explain specific tweaks to the config.xml

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File

From the doc

For projects created with the Cordova CLI (described in The Command-line Interface The Command-line Interface), this file can be found in the top-level www directory. Using the CLI to build a project regenerates versions of this file in various subdirectories within platforms .Ifyou usetheCLI to create a project, but then shift your workflow to an SDK, the platform-specific file serves as a source.